# How to create a loop with wheel picker in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop week days in this manner,

SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN, MON, TUE,...

like in horizontal circle, For this I am using this Repo

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vseslav/react-native-horizontal-picker

but the issue is when I reach to the end it gives me blank space, I want loop to repeat itself and connect like a circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the `.shift()` and `.push()` array methods:**

```
let array = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
array.push(array.shift());  // results in ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN']
```

Comment: is there any way to do this infinite times?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHFH9.jpg like this

Comment: Well for sure there is a way... You could use `for` loop or `while` loop, thats the first in my mind but i bet there are other solutions as well.

Comment: This may help: https://greensock.com/draggable  EDIT: And here: https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Draggable